# Flowable.concatMapEagerDelayError doesn't work as expected, subscription on the next item is not performed if first is not completed yet (v2.2.6)

Tags: rx-java2

RxJava v2.2.6

I use Flowable.concatMapEagerDelayError
with concurrency=2 if first item is slow, second is fast, it doesn't start processing third item

I expect that subscription to third item will happen even if first item is not completed yet.
How can I archive this?

Code:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
Flowable.just(10000L, 100L, 200L)
        .concatMapEagerDelayError(i -> Flowable
                        .just(i)
                        .delay(i, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + "ms: subscribe " + i))
                        .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + "ms: complete " + i))
                , 2
                , 100
                , true
        )
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time + "ms: fired " + i))
        .blockingSubscribe();
```

Output:

```
146ms: subscribe 10000
148ms: subscribe 100
253ms: complete 100
10152ms: fired 10000
10152ms: complete 10000
10152ms: subscribe 200
10153ms: fired 100
10353ms: fired 200
10353ms: complete 200
```

Comment: It works as intended. The operator will hold onto a limited number of items from a limited number of sources at a time so there is no excess and unbounded memory usage. Once a source is completely consumed, it will move onto the next source.

Comment: I understand though this is not well described in javadoc.

Comment: What operator/combination should I use to I archive the functionality I need?

Comment: There is no standard operator that can get you that pattern. If you know the number of sources, you can build up a pyramid: `concatEager(source1, concatEager(source2, source3, 1, 128))`

Comment: @akarnokd please note that in docs you note that it subscribes all publishers: "Eager concatenation means that once a subscriber subscribes, this operator subscribes to all of the source Publishers."

Comment: Please note that the document has many copy-paste simplifications and thus is not always adapted to the particular operator. PR welcome.

Comment: I actually need to process many items from Flowable but at most X at a time and then get ordered results. It sounds quite simple, but cannot be easily done with RxJava.

Comment: You most likely need a custom operator for that type of pattern.